# Select and populate don't work together Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to populate the `menteeList.userRecord` and only select the name and profile. BUT populate the profile as well. However, if I do the following:

```
    Profile.findOne({ user: req.user._id }).populate({
            path: 'menteeList.userRecord',
            populate: { path: 'name profile', 
             select:'name profile',
                   populate: { path: 'profile_picture' }, select: 
                     'profile_picture' }
                    })
```

It will only show the name and will just show the profile Id `"profile": "5c9ae48eedd2dd561c09083c"`

If I do this:

```
   Profile.findOne({ user: req.user._id }).populate({path: 'menteeList.userRecord',populate: { path: 'profile_picture' }, 
select: 'profile_picture' }})
```

Then it will populate all fields no problem, but I am trying to select JUST the name and populated profile (I just used this example to show that the path definitions are correct)

**MenteeList definition in currently fetched Profile document**

```
menteeList: [
        {
            name: { type: String, required: true },
            avatar: { type: String, required: true },
            userRecord: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        }
    ]
```

**Profile definition in User Schema**

```
name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    profile: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Profile'
        },
```

Comment: Can you show me your profile schema, i think you have added  `menteeList` and `User` schema, but missed `profile` schema

Comment: Add all the schema : `Profile`, `User` separately, its a little confusing right now

Answer (score 0):

From reference of your second query, I think your first query is wrong,

Try this:

```
Profile
    .findOne({ user: req.user._id })
    .populate({
        path: 'menteeList.userRecord',
        select:'name profile profile_picture',
        populate: { 
            path: 'profile_picture',
            select: 'profile_picture'
        }
    })
```

This will tell `mongodb` to populate `userRecord`, and select only `name`, `profile` and `profile_picture` (since we need to populate `profile_picture` as well, we need to include it in `select` as well).

Next, we can populate `profile_picture` and select `profile_picture` from it.

I hope this helps you out.